# jQuery popup only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a simple looking problem and I have tried googling it. Though I found a few solutions, but none of them worked for me totally, which is why I am posting this question.
I have a javascript function triggered by events which creates an AJAX request that returns a result which then pops up. My problem is that the pop up is coming again and again, every time the event is triggered. I need the pop up to go off only once until the page is reloaded. I have added the relative part of the code. Please, any help would be appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'index.php?module=Leads&action=FindDuplicate',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {name, dob},
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (result) {
            if(result != null){                    
                alert(result);                  
            } 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a boolean flag.

Ex.

```js
(function() {

  var flag = false;

  //Ajax Success Function
  function mySuccessFn() {

    if (flag) return;

    alert("Example");

    flag = true;

  }

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',
    mySuccessFn);

})();
```

```html
<button>Example</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your file put a global varbiale:

Var alreadyOpened =false;

Inside you success function, if result is defined, before to alert the result, check if this variable is false.
If it is, alert the message and set it to true. 
It should be alerted again once after the page has been reloaded

Comment: You're welcome :) 
Could you please vote up this as well? Thanks

Comment: I did, but it doesnt show publicly as I am a newbie here! 15 reps is required it shows!

Comment: oh cool :D thanks anyway, I am newbie too so I can understand you!